# Finding similar documents with Elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, similarity, tf-idf

I'm using ElasticSearch to develop service that will store uploaded files or web pages as attachment (file is one field in document). This part works fine as I can search these files using like_text as input. However, the second part of this service should compare the file that is just uploaded with the existing files in order to find duplicates or very similar files, so it doesn't recommend users same files or same web pages. The problem is that I can't get expected results for documents that are the same. Similarity between same files varies, but is never more then 0.4. Even worse, sometimes I get better scores for files which are not the same then for two exactly the same files. The java code give bellow gives me always the set of documents which are in the same order, regardless of the input. It looks like like_text extracted from uploaded file is always the same.

```
String mapping = copyToStringFromClasspath("/org/prosolo/services/indexing/documents- mapping.json");
byte[] txt = org.elasticsearch.common.io.Streams.copyToByteArray(file);
Client client = ElasticSearchFactory.getClient();
client.admin().indices().putMapping(putMappingRequest(indexName).type(indexType).source(mapping)).actionGet();
IndexResponse iResponse = client.index(indexRequest(indexName).type(indexType)
            .source(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                .field("file", txt)
                .field("title",title)
                    .field("visibility",visibilityType.name().toLowerCase())
                .field("ownerId",ownerId)
                .field("description",description)
                .field("contentType",DocumentType.DOCUMENT.name().toLowerCase())
                .field("dateCreated",dateCreated)
                .field("url",link)
                .field("relatedToType",relatedToType)
                .field("relatedToId",relatedToId)
                .endObject()))
            .actionGet();
 client.admin().indices().refresh(refreshRequest()).actionGet();

  MoreLikeThisRequestBuilder mltRequestBuilder=new MoreLikeThisRequestBuilder(client, ESIndexNames.INDEX_DOCUMENTS,    ESIndexTypes.DOCUMENT, iResponse.getId());
  mltRequestBuilder.setField("file");
  SearchResponse response = client.moreLikeThis(mltRequestBuilder.request()).actionGet();
  SearchHits searchHits= response.getHits();
  System.out.println("getTotalHits:"+searchHits.getTotalHits());
  Iterator<SearchHit> hitsIter=searchHits.iterator();
  while(hitsIter.hasNext()){
    SearchHit searchHit=hitsIter.next();
    System.out.println("FOUND DOCUMENT:"+searchHit.getId()+" title:"+searchHit.getSource().get("title")+" score:"+searchHit.score());
}
```

And the query from browser which looks like:

```
http://localhost:9200/documents/document/m2HZM3hXS1KFHOwvGY1pVQ/_mlt?mlt_fields=file&min_doc_freq=1
```

Gives me results:

```
   {"took":120,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},
   "hits":{"total":4,
   "max_score":0.41059873,
    "hits":
      [{"_index":"documents","_type":"document",
      "_id":"gIe6NDEWRXWTMi4kMPRbiQ",
      "_score":0.41059873, 
      "_source" : 
             {"file":"PCFET0NUWVBFIGh..._skiping_the_file_content_here...",
              "title":"Univariate Analysis",
              "visibility":"public",
              "description":"Univariate Analysis Simple Tools for Description ",
              "contentType":"webpage",
              "dateCreated":"null",
              "url":"http://www.slideshare.net/christineshearer/univariate-analysis"}}
```

This is exactly the same web page, so I'm expecting the score to be 1.0, not 0.41 as there is not difference between two documents except in _id. The results are even worse with files.

Mapping I was using is:

```
{
 "document":{
   "properties":{
      "title":{
            "type":"string",
            "store":true
        },
      "description":{
             "type":"string",
             "store":"yes"
       },
      "contentType":{
             "type":"string",
             "store":"yes"
       },
      "dateCreated":{
             "store":"yes",
             "type":"date"
       },
      "url":{
             "store":"yes",
            "type":"string"
      },
      "visibility": {
             "store":"yes",
            "type":"string"
      },
      "ownerId": {
            "type": "long",
            "store":"yes"
      },
      "relatedToType": {
            "type": "string",
            "store":"yes"
      },
      "relatedToId": {
            "type": "long",
            "store":"yes"
      },
      "file":{
            "path": "full",
            "type":"attachment",
            "fields":{
                "author": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "title": {
                    "store": true,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "keywords": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "file": {
                    "store": true,
                    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "content_length": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "date": {
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "content_type": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
       } } } } }
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here?

Thanks